# Getting error: Unhandled Rejection (Error): No credentials | if (typeof opt.graphql_headers !== 'undefined' && | in GraphQLAPI.ts file

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify

How to resolve this error? I am working on a react project where I am using Amplify, GrapghqlAPI's
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVFdZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Out of nowhere I also encountered the same issue. I had this with the following packages:

```
"@aws-amplify/api": "^3.2.11",
"@aws-amplify/auth": "^3.4.11",
"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^0.2.28",
"aws-amplify": "^3.3.8",
"aws-appsync": "^4.0.1",
```

Updated to the following versions, and the problem disappeared:

```
"@aws-amplify/api": "^3.2.22",
"@aws-amplify/auth": "^3.4.22",
"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^0.2.38",
"aws-amplify": "^3.3.19",
"aws-appsync": "^4.0.3",
```

According to the changelogs of [aws-amplify](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/aws-amplify/CHANGELOG.md) and [aws-amplify/auth](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/auth/CHANGELOG.md) there are no notable changes between these versions, so I am not sure what was actually fixed.